# how to modify a text file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file named ama.txt and the content of the file is like this:

```
name      age   hobby       sex

amit      45    music       male

sumit     35    cricket     female
```

Now I can open the file like this:

```
File.open("ama.txt").each do

end
```

How can I modify the `hobby` column of the file?

Answer (score 16):

The general pattern for something like this is roughly as follows:

1. Open the original file for reading and a new file for writing. Read the original line by line.
2. Skip any lines that aren't relevant (you want to skip your header line and the blanks, for example)
3. Deal with the individual lines however you need. Here you probably want something like `cols = line.split(/\s+/)` and then you want to edit `cols[2]`, though I don't know if the changes fit a pattern or what.
4. Once you have the edits made, print the edited line out to *the new file*.
5. Once you're done with reading the original and writing the changed lines to the new file, close both files.
6. Change the original's name to something like 'original_name' + '.bak' and the new file's name to 'original_name'.
7. Done.

Ruby, like most scripting languages, has a lot of built-in ways to make some of these steps go quicker, but that's the basic pattern. Dmitry is potentially right that a CSV reader would help you here, but I can't see how well-formatted (or not) your data is, so I'm not even going to get into that.

Finally, and not to be rude, but it doesn't seem that you know Ruby especially well. Why is Ruby a requirement? Do you know another scripting language? How well do you know Ruby? In general, people here will help you with things, but not simply write code for you.

To answer Amit's question about step 4: If you have a new file open for writing, you will have a filehandle - a variable in your program pointing to the open file. You can write to that file by using the filehandle as a receiver for `puts`. This looks weird at first, since `puts` looks like a function normally, but it *is* [a method call in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Kernel.html#M001105). Try this in `irb` or a short Ruby script:

```
fh = File.open('test.txt', 'w')
fh.puts "hello, world"
fh.close
```

Another short example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
out_file = File.open('output.txt', 'w')

File.open('input.txt', 'r').each do |line|
  out_file.print line.sub('foo', 'bar')
end

out_file.close
# no need to close the input file since the block version closes it for us
# automagically

# Maybe better to put the whole thing in a double block, though you may
# find this harder to follow at first
File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |out_file|
  File.open('input.txt', 'r').each do |line|
    out_file.print line.sub('foo', 'bar')
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks tele but could i get some code means what you wrote its implementation . yaa tele i just started ruby for my colleage project

Comment: yaa okk you are saying right noone write code for me thanks for your help

Comment: and tele what u said will not work either so next time come up something different

Comment: yaa tele that fh is file handle or object and i used it before but sumthing i wrote
path="c:/put/ama12.txt"
File.readlines(path).each do |$line| 
  $row = $line.chomp.split('\t') # use your delimiter symbol 
  
  $row[2] ="raman"
end
fh = File.open('test.txt', 'w') 
fh.puts $row
fh.close 
but nothing happening for me

Comment: @amit Nothing happens because you're trying to do the writing _after_ you've already finished all the reading. Check my outline again. You open both files (the one you read from, and the one you will write to) _earlier_. Then, after you get each line from the one you read, you write it out to the other at the same time. I'll add an example above, but you really need to read your textbook or see your teacher.

Comment: When I tried your example, it did not seem to close the input file properly until it exited the script. So I split `File.open('input.txt', 'r').each do |line|` into two nested blocks: `File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |file|` with an inner `file.each do |line|` block and that worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.readlines("ama.txt").each do |line|
  row = line.strip.split('\t') # use your delimiter symbol
  row[2] = ... # hobby column
end
```

Or just use [fastercsv](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) gem.

Comment: Dmitry i have to put this code in file.open("ama.txt).each do
end ??

Comment: Tele its not working i want to modify the  values of hobby column how to do that??

Comment: nd File.open is not returing array of line like when i tried to do like puts "#{line[0]}" i am not getting any value

Comment: and one more i wouls like to have these changes must be reflected in ama.txt file

Comment: I forgot each, just added it.

Comment: path="c:/put/ama12.txt" 
path1="c:/put/ama1.txt" 
out_file = File.open(path1, 'w') 
x=0 
File.open(path, 'r').each do |line|
 $row = line.chomp.split("\t") 
if(x==1)
 $row[0]="sdrom"
 line=$row
 puts 
end 
x=x+1 
out_file.print "#{line}"
 end 
out_file.close

Comment: this is what i did but the problem i have is my output is like
name age hobby sex 
sdrom45cricketmale 
 the sencond line should be tab saprated how to do  it tele??