# Delete a line of information from a text file

Tags: ruby

I have a text file called text.txt, and it has the following text:

```
123,shirt,9.99 
234,pants,19.50
456,socks,3.99
```

How do I delete one row (e.g 123,shirt,9.99).  How would I go about deleting this row?

My code so far:

```
 test_file = File.new('text.txt', "a")
 while (line = test_file)
   puts 'Enter the products item number you wish to delete. '
   user_delete = gets.chomp.to_i
   line.delete(user_delete)
 end
```

Comment: 'a' simply appends to the file, it won't remove anything.

Comment: so if i want to delete something out do i use 'r+' ?

Answer (score 1):

You're making a lot of mistakes here.

First of all opening the file with `a` (you need to use `r+` or `w+`).

In Ruby we use a [more elegant](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line) to iterate over files.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638667/how-do-i-remove-lines-of-data-in-the-middle-of-a-text-file-with-ruby), it will help you with your problem.

After that a look at [IO library](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/IO.html) to understand how it all works

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there are a bunch of better ways to do this, but here's quick and dirty:

```
puts "What's the item number?"
item_num = gets.chomp

read_file = File.new('read.txt', "r").read
write_file = File.new('read.txt', "w")

read_file.each_line do |line|
  write_file.write(line) unless line.include? item_num
end
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what i was looking for. Basically just reading the file and re writing it up to the item number. Thanks!

Comment: NP.  Feel free to accept and/or upvote this answer if it addressed your issue.