# Move line from one text file to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of names (`names.txt`) separated by line. After I loop through each line, I'd like to move it to another file (`processed.txt`).

My current implementation to loop through each line:

```
open("names.txt") do |csv|
  csv.each_line do |line|
    url = line.split("\n")
    puts url
    # Remove line from this file amd move it to processed.txt
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
File.open('processed.txt', 'a') do |file|
  open("names.txt") do |csv|
    csv.each_line do |line|
      url = line.chomp
      # Do something interesting with url...
      file.puts url
    end
  end
end
```

This will result in `processed.txt` containing all of the urls that were processed with this code.

Note: Removing the line from `names.txt` is not practical using this method.  See [How do I remove lines of data in the middle of a text file with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638667/how-do-i-remove-lines-of-data-in-the-middle-of-a-text-file-with-ruby) for more information.  If this is a real goal of this solution, it will be a much larger implementation with some design considerations that need to be defined.

Comment: Thanks. Since removing the line is not practical, would it be possible to add a character to the beginning of the line (to mark it as completed?)

Comment: That is possible, and if the `names.txt` file will be (fairly) small, we could possibly rewrite the file after processing, omitting the first line.  Is this file large or is it manageable?

Comment: Actually, I think ill just write the current line to a new file with each iteration of the loop. Then I'll know which line was processed. Is that a more practical approach?

Comment: It might be.  If your script fails while processing, will you need to be able to start where it failed, or is it acceptable to start at the beginning again?  I do think it's possible to build what you need, so that you don't need to make a compromise.  File size of `names.txt` will determine which is the best approach to take, and I think I can come up with something that works for you if I know how big it will be (lines or bytes).

Comment: The file size of `names.txt` is around 50mb (30-80mb range). And yes, it needs to start where it failed. It cannot start from the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: @Onichan Thanks for the details.  I'll put together a solution that I think will work.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of just using `next if index < current_line` where `current_line` is the saved line. But that requires the program to loop through the entire list everytime it fails/stops. Is there a better way to skip to a particular line?

Comment: Nothing better than that.  At least that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

```
def readput 
  @names = File.readlines("names.txt") 
  File.open("processed.txt", "w+") do |f| 
    f.puts(@names) 
  end 
end
```