# Read from a file and Update

Tags: ruby

i have a text file called text.txt with stored text like so

713,socks,3.99

888,hat,12.99

634,shirt,7.99

I want to open my file and choose a item number then i want to update the description and price. and save that back to the file.

heres my code so far

```
puts "Whats's the item number of the product you wish to update?"
item_num = gets.chomp
puts 'Enter new products description. '
new_description = gets.chomp
puts 'Enter new products price. '
new_price = gets.chomp.to_s
open('text.txt', 'r+') { |update|
update.puts "#{item_num},#{new_description},#{new_price}"
}
end
```

all this is doing is adding a new product with the same item number.

Comment: You have to read the _flat file_ and then write the updated one in a new file, and save the new file. This is how it works,

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289653/how-to-modify-a-text-file-in-ruby

Comment: Do you really want the file to be in `CSV` itself? It may be easier to have it formatted as `YAML`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve a goal is to use [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class to operate your file content. After all, the content *is* csv, right?

So, instead of:

```
open('text.txt', 'r+') { |update|
  update.puts "#{item_num},#{new_description},#{new_price}"
}
```

you might want to search for an element inside loaded array, update it and then write the content back to file:

```
require 'csv'
items = CSV.read("text.txt")
items.map! { |i| 
  next i unless i.first == item_num # skip unless it’s our item 
  i[1] = new_description
  i[2] = new_price
  i 
}

# here should go the code whether you need to insert line if `num` is not found

CSV.open("text.txt", "wb") do |csv|
  items.each { |i| csv << i }
end
```

This is definitely not a best production-quality code, the intent was to demonstrate how it’s to be done in general. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, i don't really know what .map! is doing but a little research will help!